# Create or copy files outside of target folders | Xcode 6 Custom Project Templates

Tags: xcode, templates, gitignore, readme

I’m trying to create a custom Xcode 6 project template. Standard file layout when I create a project using Single View project looks like this:

```
ProjectName
—>ProjectName
—>ProjectName.xcodeproj
—>ProjectNameTests
```

How can I add files to this top level using the custom xcode template? I would like to add .gitignore and README.md files so it would look like this:

```
ProjectName
—>.gitignore
—>ProjectName
—>ProjectName.xcodeproj
—>ProjectNameTests
—>README.md
```